# insert foreign key from JComboBox

Tags: java, combobox

I want to save the key from a java combobox selected item i made this function so i could return the primery key of table "nationality" and insert it as foreign key in other tables but it doesn't work it return always 0:

```
public int getNat() throws Exception{
    String query = "SELECT code_nat FROM nationality WHERE nationality=?";
       try ( PreparedStatement stat = cnx.prepareStatement(query) ) {

          stat.setString(1, (String)cmbNat.getSelectedItem());
          rslt = stat.executeQuery();
          return rslt.getInt(1);

       }catch(SQLException ex){
              ex.printStackTrace();
              return 0; 
       }
}
```

Comment: Your query should go more along the lines of "SELECT nationality_field FROM nationality_table"

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work".  What errors are you getting

Answer (score 1):

you cannot select all fields of the table:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM nationality WHERE nationality=?";
//                     ↑ here
```

Use the field name instead:

```
String query = "SELECT nationality_id FROM nationality WHERE nationality=?";
```

Also to [retrieve data check here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) but this must work

```
return rs.getInt("nationality_id");
```

Comment: because you need to take result column number 0 `rslt.getInt(0);`

Comment: also... `cmbNat.getSelectedItem()` returns nationality name or id? why are you casting it to `String` ?

Comment: sorry i couldn't past all exceptions in here

Comment: because the combobox is fill with Strings with nationality labels but i need to return the key of the selected one

Comment: your query works in sql directly? if so, check my update and get column by name `rs.getInt("nationality_id ")`

Comment: *because the combobox is fill with Strings with nationality labels but i need to return the key* that does not make sense, I'm asking **why are you casting combo box content to `String`** here `stat.setString(1, (String)cmbNat.getSelectedItem());`

Comment: i cast it because getSelectedItem returns an object if i don't cast it, it make error,

Comment: the query directly from localhost is working but by java code no

Comment: *sorry i couldn't past all exceptions in here* do you have exceptions? which ones? please paste at least first lines to see why/where is JVM complaining

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:787)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2460)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2571)
 at brsClasses.Info.getNat(Info.java:85)
 at brsClasses.Info.insertInfo(Info.java:96)

Comment: getNat is the function i posted, insertInfo is the function of insertion

Comment: i don't know what to add but the insertion works only the field code_nat (the foreign key) return always 0 not the value corresponding to the selected item

Answer (score 0):

the insertion function

```
public void insertInfo() throws Exception{
    try{
        int codeNat = getNat();

        String query = "INSERT INTO info (id,name,code_nat) VALUES (?,?,?)";

        stat = cnx.prepareStatement(query);
        stat.setString(1, txtId.getText());
        stat.setString(2, txtName.getText());
        stat.setInt(3, codeNat);

        stat.execute();
        Update_table();

    }catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
    }
    finally{
        try{
            stat.close();
            cnx.close();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```